# Heroku Error H10 (App crashed) - Install Redmine 2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, redmine

Although read many articles about this problem, I still couldn't solve those error,
Here is a part of the heroku logs, if it's less-information, I would update others code of the red mine source code.

```
2012-11-05T14:02:54+00:00 app[web.1]: Plugins in vendor/plugins (/app/vendor/plugins) are no longer allowed. Please, put your Redmine plugins in the `plugins` directory at the root of your Redmine directory (/app/plugins)    
2012-11-05T14:02:54+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick    
2012-11-05T14:02:54+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.8 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:40115    
2012-11-05T14:02:54+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach    
2012-11-05T14:02:54+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server    
2012-11-05T14:02:54+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting    
2012-11-05T14:02:55+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1    
2012-11-05T14:02:55+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed    
2012-11-05T14:02:56+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET ceciits.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=    
2012-11-05T14:06:04+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to down    
2012-11-05T14:06:04+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling    
2012-11-05T14:06:04+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting    
2012-11-05T14:06:07+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 3103`    
2012-11-05T14:06:12+00:00 app[web.1]: Plugins in vendor/plugins (/app/vendor/plugins) are no longer allowed. Please, put your Redmine plugins in the `plugins` directory at the root of your Redmine directory (/app/plugins)    
2012-11-05T14:06:12+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2012-11-05T14:06:12+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.8 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3103
2012-11-05T14:06:12+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2012-11-05T14:06:12+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl -C to shutdown server
2012-11-05T14:06:12+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting    
2012-11-05T14:06:13+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-11-05T14:06:13+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I can't figure where is the reason that leads app crashed actually,
Thanks for answering...

Comment: Have you actually did this : "Plugins in vendor/plugins (/app/vendor/plugins) are no longer allowed. Please, put your     Redmine plugins in the `plugins` directory at the root of your Redmine directory (/app/plugins) " ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just out of curiosity, did you happen to generate your secret key?

Try running:
`heroku run rake generate_secret_token`

Not sure if it will help, but I know I've had an issue with this before.

Comment: Correct!
I try to reset my environment and final discovered the one of problems is that I never running `heroku run rake generate_secret_token`...